# Laravel 5 - Authorization

Tags: authorization, laravel-5, middleware

I have a Laravel 5 application and require to implement a authorization using middleware. I have used "Entrust" (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) for authorization.

My issue is, how I authorize each request (users/index, users/create, users/store etc.) inside of handle method of my middleware.

I can check Auth::user()->can('create-user') but require to check with each request dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my impelementation of such middleware:

```
class Authenticate {

    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = \Request::header('x-auth-token');

        // common login functionality
        if ($token) {
            $authtoken = \App\Models\Authtoken::find($token);
            if ($authtoken) {
                \Auth::loginUsingId($authtoken->user_id);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Authtoken is a eloquent model over `authtokens` table. Of course you can retrieve a user id some other way.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, But what I really want is to check a user can do a given task (can-update-user). I have stored permissions by user role in a table. With "Entrust" I can check Auth::user()->can('update-user'). But how I identify each request dynamically and check against the permission.

Comment: It's similar to the code I provided. You'd need to get a current route from a request and check whatever you need. In case the user doesn't have sufficient rights you'd return some json with error instead of `return $next($request)`